# Uneven distribution of tasks among workers in Spark/GraphX 1.5.0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, apache-spark-1.5

I have a large list of edges as a 5000 partition RDD. Now, I'm doing a simple but
shuffle-heavy operation:

```
val g = Graph.fromEdges(edges, ...).partitionBy(...)
val subs = Graph(g.collectEdges(...), g.edges).collectNeighbors()
subs.saveAsObjectFile("hdfs://...")
```

The job gets divided into 9 stages (5000 tasks each). My cluster has 3 workers in the same local network.
Even though Spark 1.5.0 works much faster and first several stages run on the full load,
starting from one of the stages (`mapPartitions at GraphImpl.scala:235`), a single machine suddenly takes 99% of the tasks
while others take as many tasks as they have cores and those tasks stay `RUNNING` until the one machine that actually works
finishes everything. Interestingly, on Spark 1.3.1, all stages get their tasks distributed
evenly among the cluster machines. I'm suspecting that this could be a bug in 1.5.0

**UPD:** It seems like the problem is not data related: I have randomly generated a highly homogeneous graph (each vertex has degree 5) and observed identical behavior. So this is either a strange hardware problem or tungsten-related issue. Still no exact answer

Comment: which stage is generating only one task?

Comment: neither. I guess I didn't explain it well. All stages have 5000 tasks. It's just that one of the stages (`mapPartitions at GraphImpl.scala:235`) gives like 4900 tasks to only one machine, and the rest of machines have all their tasks in the `RUNNING` state until the stage is over.

Comment: @Gillespie forgot to mention you in the previous comment

Comment: Have you tried using the spark-1.5 branch? It seems that the last distribution release contains lots of bugs. Can you do that a let us know.

Comment: You mean branch-1.5 on github? No, so far I have used prebuilt spark 1.5.0 from the website. I'll try building 1.5.2 from the aforementioned branch and report here

Comment: Experienced the same problem with Spark 1.5 on a non-trivial PageRank (originally tried 322 million edges, but even at 70 million edges and 400GB of RAM across the cluster/4 workers was still running OOM: heap space). Noticed that pretty much everything was on one worker right before crashing every time.

Comment: @eliasah tried latest 1.5 branch. Same problem. It's really hard to pinpoint the issue. Maybe it's skewed data... Do you have any idea how to investigate this?

Comment: If I can't reproduce the issue, I can't help you investigate. Nevertheless, spark 1.5.1 has been released. You can recheck on that. And try to benchmark incrementally with a different size of data.